# How to resolve variables in Apache ANT inside Javascript task

Tags: javascript, ant

I am calling javascript from Apache ANT via this task:

```
<property name="myprop" value="someval" />
<script language="javascript" src="mytask.js" />
```

And inside js I have variable `foo`:

```
 var foo = '${myprop} - bar';
```

How can I resolve variable `foo` for properties from owning ANT file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is undocumented method `project.replaceProperties` that takes a string and returns the string. Ie:

```
project.replaceProperties('foo - ${myprop}');
```

I found out of it by running following code which lists all methods from given Java object:

```
function log(str)
{
    var echo = project.createTask("echo");
    echo.setMessage(str);
    echo.perform();
}

function getAllMethods(object) {
    return Java.from(object.class.getDeclaredMethods());
}

var all = getAllMethods(project);
for(var a = 0; a < all.length; a++)
    log(all[a]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the examples in the [`script`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) task documentation, a property can be retrieved from the provided `project` reference:

```
<property name="fs.dir" value="src"/>

<target name="main">
    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[

    // Access to Ant-Properties by their names
    dir = project.getProperty("fs.dir");
```

Comment: Yup, I know; I need to resolve ALL properties from given string in the form ${propname}. I hoped not to write custom function for that (which of course I can)...